# Typescript Type Exclusion?

Tags: typescript

I know of type union & type intersection in type script but I couldn't find a syntax or workaround to use type exclusion. Is there a way to do that?

```
type ValidIndices = string ^ '_reservedProperty'; // All strings but '_reservedProperty'
interface MyInterface {
    [property: ValidIndices]: number;
    _reservedProperty: any;
}
```

Comment: There's [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183) for subtraction types

Answer (score 1):

It's not a fully answer. But if you want to set exclusion for contsructor params you can use code like this:

```
declare type Params<T, K extends keyof T = never, D extends keyof T = never> = (
  {[P in K]: T[P]} &
  {[P in keyof T]?: T[P]} &
  {[P in D]?: undefined }
)
...
class Control{
  prop1: number
  prop2: number
  prop3: number
  prop4: number

  constructor(params: Params<Control, 'prop1' | 'prop2', 'prop4'>){
    Object.assign(this, params)
...
```

And you get:

```
params: {
  prop1: number
  prop2: number
  prop3?: number
  prop4?: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a limited set of string values that are allowable, then you could use string literals to define them in the type

```
type ValidIndices = "a" | "b" | "c" ...
```

However, I do not think that the functionality that you are looking for exists right now as part of a type definition.

You can of course achieve this through code in your implementation of `MyInterface` to make sure that the illegal values aren't used. But you can't make it part of the type definition itself (other than string literals, which you probably dont want).